# How to fill space between 3 points in circle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I have to points on the border of a circle and on point in the middle of the circle. I want to color the space (pie) between these three points red (including the "arc"). It dosen't have to be in svg.

```
const AzimuthChart = (props) => {
  const x1 = 428.9397
  const y1 = 159.2263 
  const x2 = 371.3345
  const y2 = 159.0330 

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 400">
        <g fill="#61DAFB">
          <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="50"/>
          <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="1" fill='red'/>
          <circle cx={x2} cy={y2} r='1' fill='red'/>
          <circle cx={x1} cy={y1} r='1' fill='red'/>
        </g>
      </svg>
      
    </div>
  )
}
```

export default AzimuthChart

This is what it looks like right now:

[image]

This is what I want it to look like:

[image]

I have tried adding an arc:

```
<path d='M 449.89 203.252 A 1 1 0 0 0 350 202.8' fill='red'/>
```

But this only created half a circle. Does someone have an idea on how to solve thes

Comment: supposing that you have `<circle cx="383.84" cy="152.68" r='3' fill='red'/>
          <circle cx="409" cy="150.81" r='3' fill='red'/>` your path can be `<path d="M400,200L383.84,152.68A50,50 0 1 0 409,150.81z"/>` ie you move to the center 400,200 Next you draw the arc choosing the largest arc. Finally you close the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just plug the points into the [elliptical arc command](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands). Noting that as you need the "big" arc rather than the "small" arc that you need to set the large-arc-flag to 1.

```js
const x1 = 428.9397
const y1 = 159.2263 
const x2 = 371.3345
const y2 = 159.0330

let path = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'path');

path.setAttribute("d", `M ${x2} ${y2} A 50 50 0 1 0 ${x1} ${y1} L 400 200 Z`)
path.setAttribute("fill", "red");

document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0].appendChild(path);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 800 400">
  <circle cx="400" cy="200" r="50" fill="#61DAFB"/>
</svg>
```